# How to remove or get the position of a certain node in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I have a sprite kit game for Mac where I have multiple sprite nodes moving across the screen. How do I make it so I can `removeFromParent` a certain node?
For example, I have a loop that periodically adds a new node every second:

```
-(void)spawnNew {
xPos = 100;
yPos = 1000;
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
orb = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"orb"];
orb.position = location;
orb.scale = 0.3;
orb.name = @"orbSprite";
CGFloat dirX = 0;
CGFloat dirY = -30;
CGVector vector1 = CGVectorMake(dirX, dirY);
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveBy:vector1 duration:0.1];
[orb runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:action count:100000]];
[self addChild:orb];

}
```

How would I make it so that I can get the position or remove certain orbs, not the entire group? For example, if the position of a sprite is equal to `x=100, y=200` then I would remove it from parent. Currently if I try to do this and check for an orb's position, it just checks the position of the newest orb to be added, not all of them which I would want.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient answer but it does show how you might do this. keep in mind that generally with Sprite Kit your going to end up with a lot of nodes so grouping them under a parent `SKNode` is a good idea, it also lets to specify a point in the tree so you can easily get the children below it. The `NSLog` statements are just for testing/debug, I left then in as they may help if you try the code.

```
- (void)addOrbs {
    SKNode *orbRoot = [SKNode node];
    [orbRoot setName:@"ORB_ROOT"];
    [self addChild:orbRoot];

    for(int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++) {
        SKSpriteNode *newOrb = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
        [newOrb setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100 + (100*counter))];
        NSLog(@"ORB POS: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([newOrb position]));
        [newOrb setName:@"orbSprite"];
        [orbRoot addChild:newOrb];
    }
}
```

.

```
- (void)removeOrbAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    SKNode *orbRoot = [self childNodeWithName:@"//ORB_ROOT"];
    NSArray *allOrbs = [orbRoot children];
    NSLog(@"ORBS: %@", allOrbs);
    for(SKNode *eachOrb in allOrbs) {
        if([eachOrb position].x == 100 && [eachOrb position].y == 200) {
            NSLog(@"REMOVING: %@ WITH POSITION: %@", [eachOrb name], NSStringFromCGPoint([eachOrb position]));
            [eachOrb removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```

An alternate version of remove using fast block enumeration:

```
- (void)removeOrbAtPoint_v2:(CGPoint)point {
    SKNode *orbRoot = [self childNodeWithName:@"//ORB_ROOT"];
    NSArray *allOrbs = [orbRoot children];
    NSLog(@"ORBS: %@", allOrbs);
    [orbRoot enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"orbSprite" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if([node position].x == 100 && [node position].y == 200) {
            NSLog(@"REMOVING: %@ WITH POSITION: %@", [node name], NSStringFromCGPoint([node position]));
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach - You can add the removeFromParent into an action sequence.  This will automatically remove it when it gets to a defined point, with no additional code.

Would changing your `moveBy:` action to a `moveTo:` work?

```
SKAction *moveToFinish  = [SKAction moveTo:finishPoint duration:5.0];
SKAction *removeMe = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *actionSeq = [SKAction sequence:@[moveToFinish,removeMe]];
[sprite runAction:actionSeq];
```

My finishPoint is generated by a random statement to give it some variety.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the nodes in the node or scene you are adding the orbs to.

```
for(SKNode * child in self.children) {
 ...
}
```

See if they are within this box.

```
for(SKNode * child in self.children) {
   if(CGRectIntersectsRect(child.calculateAccumulatedFrame, CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 200))) {
      ...        
   }
}
```

Remove the child (CGRectMake takes x,y,width,height as parameters)

```
for(SKNode * child in self.children) {
   if(CGRectIntersectsRect(child.calculateAccumulatedFrame, CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 200))) {
      [child removeFromParent];       
   }
}
```